# Some users are unable to connect to Firestore. What could be causing it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We've developed an app based on Firestore, and sporadically some users report that the app is not working for them. We have found that in these cases the users are able to access our other resources, and are also able to authenticate with Firebase, but are unable to retrieve documents from the database.

I have created a troubleshooting page, where I only use the direct Firestore APIs to make sure that the problem is not in any of our abstractions or other depencencies. On this page I am calling `getDocFromServer` and `getDocsFromServer` and the user sees the following errors:

[image: Database errors]

We've asked the user to switch of any VPN, and try a different browser and different network, and they claim to have tried those things, so I am running out of ideas.

Comment: You should log their IP address, time of access, and their ability to communicate with a variety of things other than Firestore.  What you're showing right now is not really actionable - it's just saying that the client is not connected to the service, with no indication why or any other contextual information.  Also consider instead posting your information to [google-cloud-firestore-discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss) to get better help, potentially from Google stuff.  As a community, SO is likely not very prepared to help you understand what might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I will do that. I've also contacted Firebase support on this. The page does show some auth info, which I guess proves that they are able to communicate with Firebase, but I've left it out in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure what time of access could tell us. These users are consistently not able to connect, so I don't think time is a factor.

Comment: I will also add a section to the troubleshooting page that forces long polling https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are likely caused the either a VPN or proxy. Enabling auto detect long polling might solve the issue for some clients.

Here is the [Firebase issue discussing these problems](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674)

There is also a Firebase connection debugging page at:

https://debug-my.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I can confirm that auto-detect long-polling did indeed solve the problem for our users.